# Canvas rectangles drawings

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, draw

I am trying to draw two rectangles one to another but with different colours.

I am calling drawing like this:

```
canvas.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
canvas.drawRect(0,50,50,100);
```

After the rectangles are drawn I can see line tick 1px between these two rectangles.

Can you tell me what is wrong with my logic?

Comment: I am sorry but your question is unclear what do you mean by two rectangles one to another? do you mean next to each other, on each other ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, next to each other. I can see the backgtound color between these two rectangles. Gap is wide 1px

Comment: Paste the part of the code that sets up your `Paint` object